# Power Bi not Connecting to Oracle

Tags: powerbi

When i am connecting to Oracle from Power Bi Desktop I am facing this Details:
"An error happened while reading data from the provider: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object" Issue Please helpme ,

Comment: you need to give the complete string of oracle to get connected

Answer (score 0):

Hi which version of PBI you have 64bit 32bit? If you have 64bit PBI and Oracle client was 32bit this is issue. Version should be same otherwise it's going to give this issues.